# How can I reinit or clear google maps infowindow cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a nested carousel inside of a gmaps infowindow, the top level carousel keeps track of all of the nested slides. It works perfect on the first infowindow instance, but when I click another marker and when the next infowindow opens the count is based off of the previous infowindow..

is there a way to destory the last instance of the infowindow?

Comment: Most likely (but probably will involve whatever code you are using for the carousel).  What does your code look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Here is a js fiddle, for the carousel and rendering the infoboxes. 
link - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fncopkLt/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't do anything useful: `Uncaught ReferenceError: SearchMapInfoBoxMulti is not defined`.  Please create a [mcve] **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue, had to change the event listener to just addListenerOnce.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13975721)

Comment: Despite the comment, please don't edit this into the question, as it **is** an answer. @beerwin, you may want to review this review...